# Java - when does java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError occur?

Tags: java, exception, classloader

Imagine I have a class called A and a constructor that throws an exception of type B.

If I do `A a = new A();` and my classpath doesn't contain B, will a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error always be thrown? Or would it only be thrown if the constructor actually threw the Exception?

```
public class A{
   public A() throws B{
       if (...){
       } else {
          throw new B();
       } 
   }


}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I suspected.

Comment: @BackSlash ".. a constructor *that throws an exception of type B*."?

Comment: @BackSlash & David: Am I somehow misunderstanding *"...and a constructor that throws an exception of type B."*? That sounds a lot like it uses `B` to me.

Comment: Seems easy enough to try and see.

Comment: @immibis yes, you have a point :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `NoClassDefFoundError` is always thrown when class loader tries to load class directly referenced in your code and cannot be found in class path.

If however you try to load this class dynamically, for example using `Class.forName()` `ClassNotFoundException` will be thrown.

Comment: This isn't clear though. Is a method signature a direct reference? In other words, would A() always throw ClassNotFound even if the Exception is not actually thrown?

Comment: @DavidBrossard: Why don't you just try it? I did, it took all of two minutes. Yes, the class def exception is thrown even if `A` never calls `new B`. In my case, I used an argument: `if (n == 0) { throw new B(); }` but then passed in a value that wasn't `0`.

Comment: @DavidBrossard: FYI: http://pastie.org/9452662 (AlexR, I thought editing it into your answer was a bit too much of an edit of someone else's answer, but feel free if you like). But note that if you comment out the `if` block that *may* throw `B`, it works without the no class def exception.

Comment: Direct reference is what is written in code. Dynamic - what is done using dynamic class loading, e.g. using `Class.forName()` or using custom class loader.

Answer (score 1):

---

WRONG ANSWER

Other answer is correct. The instantiation does not need to occur for the Error to be thrown.

---

`NoClassDefFoundError` will be thrown on runtime when you try to instantiate a class that could not be found in the classpath.

In your example it will only be thrown when the `else` block gets executed.

Doc is there: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.
>
> The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.

Comment: *"...when you try to instantiate a class..."* You don't even have to instantiate it. Having `A`'s constructor say it throws `B` is sufficient, it doesn't have to actually do it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder someone should edit this response so it is accurate. The quote is correct and  the keyword is "as part of a normal method call".

Comment: I've just run a test on my workstation and could confirm my answer. I fear @T.J.Crowder comment is not justified.
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)

Comment: @dotvav: See: http://pastie.org/9452662 But note that if you comment out the line that *may* throw `B`, it works.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see where I was wrong in my test. I used `if(true)` in my code which was optimized by the compiler and the else block was removed =). I Just checked with JD.

Comment: @dotvav, you were absolutely right when marked your own answer as wrong. I just wonder why have you posted it?

Comment: @AlexR I posted it when I thought it was right, and marked it as wrong after I discovered my mistake. I feel like I should not delete it completely as others might learn from it.

Comment: @dotvav, it is OK, do not worry. Take it easy. It is very cool that people can learn. Please pardon my sarcasm.